# I have problem in getting distinct String Value in a column using pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

This is the column that I want to work on:

[image: 1]

I want to split the genre values. *e.g.*

```
Horror 5 
Thriller 3 
.
.
.
```

like this :

[image: 2]

How can I do that ?

Update :
This is the DF I'm working on :

[image: 3]

I have tried this code :

```
TopMovies_df.genre.explode().dropna().value_counts()
```

but I got this as the output

[image: 4]

Comment: please avoid posting pictures of code. copy the code in the question using appropriate formatting so that others can better understand and reproduce your problem.

Comment: What is the numbers' source? is it count or something else?